# matplotlib text() not showing in pandas plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I can't get my text to show in my plot, axhline() shows, but not text(). I'm new to pandas and matplotlib and I'm obviously not understanding something.

[image: plot image]

```
# df is a pandas Dataframe

df_last_24 = df[df['Date']>=(dt.datetime.now()-dt.timedelta(hours=24))]

ax = df_last_24.plot.line(x="Date",title="Air Qualty Index over the last 24 hours")

# Define the date format
years_fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%I:%M %p')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(years_fmt)


plot.axhline(linewidth=4,y=300, color='#731425', linestyle='-')
plot.text(0, 300, 'Hazardous', fontsize=10, va='center', ha='left', backgroundcolor='w')

plot.axhline(linewidth=4,y=200, color='#8c1a4b', linestyle='-')
plot.text(0, 200, 'Very Unhealthy', fontsize=10, va='center', ha='left', backgroundcolor='w')

plot.axhline(linewidth=4,y=150, color='#951d47', linestyle='-')
plot.text(0, 150, 'Unhealthy', fontsize=10, va='center', ha='left', backgroundcolor='w')

plot.axhline(linewidth=4,y=100, color='#e23127', linestyle='-')
plot.text(0, 100, 'Unhealthy to Sensitive Groups', fontsize=10, va='center', ha='left', backgroundcolor='w')

plot.axhline(linewidth=4,y=50, color='#f29d3a', linestyle='-')
plot.text(0, 50, 'Moderate', fontsize=10, va='center', ha='left', backgroundcolor='w')

plot.show(block=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue was the x coordinate in the dataframe graph is a time. Using min() and datestr2num() seems to solve the issue.

```
# Find Date/Time Range
column = df_last_24['Date/Time'].dt.strftime('%a %b %d %H:%M')
subtitle = column.min() + " - " +column.max()
text_x = mdates.datestr2num(column.min())

...

# Add Level lines and Labels
ax.axhline(linewidth=4,y=300, color='#731425', linestyle='-')
ax.text(text_x, 300, 'Hazardous', fontsize=10, va='center', ha='left', backgroundcolor='w')
```

Answer (score 0):

`plt.axhline()` and `plt.` are the correct descriptions. The other graphs may have been affected by the lack of data provided. Please check with this.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.axhline(linewidth=4,y=300, color='#731425', linestyle='-')
plt.text(0, 300, 'Hazardous', fontsize=10, va='center', ha='left', backgroundcolor='w')

plt.axhline(linewidth=4,y=200, color='#8c1a4b', linestyle='-')
plt.text(0, 200, 'Very Unhealthy', fontsize=10, va='center', ha='left', backgroundcolor='w')

plt.axhline(linewidth=4,y=150, color='#951d47', linestyle='-')
plt.text(0, 150, 'Unhealthy', fontsize=10, va='center', ha='left', backgroundcolor='w')

plt.axhline(linewidth=4,y=100, color='#e23127', linestyle='-')
plt.text(0, 100, 'Unhealthy to Sensitive Groups', fontsize=10, va='center', ha='left', backgroundcolor='w')

plt.axhline(linewidth=4,y=50, color='#f29d3a', linestyle='-')
plt.text(0, 50, 'Moderate', fontsize=10, va='center', ha='left', backgroundcolor='w')

plt.show(block=True)
```

[image]